# Connecting to SP from virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, visual-studio-2012, connection

I've installed SharePoint and Visual studio on a virtual machine. Now I'm trying to add a SharePoint connection in the server explorer but it says "The site does not exist or is unavailable".

I've successfully added the server on which SharePoint is located, but I'm not able to add the SharePoint connection. If I log in on the machine where SharePoint is running then I'm able to add this connection in VS, but not from my VM.

I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure:

1. to add your site into host file on VM (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)
2. Add bindings to IIS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx)

hope it helps,

Andrew